# How to use win2d burning text in C# UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml, win2d

I want to use the **win2d** to make a burning text to my c# UWP XAML blank app project.
you can see the animation in the **win2d** example gallery app -
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/win2d-example-gallery/9nblgggxwt9f?activetab=pivot:overviewtab

I want to add this animation with specific text `tomy project` entrance how can I do it?
[Win2D in Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D)

Answer (score 0):

You need to dd the Win2D NuGet package to your project first. Here is the detailed steps that you could follow to get start:[Win2D NuGet package](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/Introduction.htm).

For your requirement, you want to add the burning effect to some text. In the sample you post, it contains the source code about how to add the burning effect.

Xaml code: [BurningTextExample-Xaml](https://github.com/microsoft/Win2D/blob/master/samples/ExampleGallery/BurningTextExample.xaml)

Code behind: [BurningTextExample-CS](https://github.com/microsoft/Win2D/blob/master/samples/ExampleGallery/BurningTextExample.xaml.cs)

You could follow these source code to create the burning effect.